# I can't connect to FDB database from Python

Tags: python, firebird

I'm triyng to connect to Firebird DB from Python. I'm using FDB module.

```
import fdb
con = fdb.connect(host='10.7.0.115',database=r'C:\ProgramData\Entensys\UserGate6\USERGATE.FDB', user='SYSDBA', password='masterkey',charset='UTF8' )


cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from baz")
for c in cur.fetchall():
    print(c)
conn.close()
```

But, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\fdb_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    con = fdb.connect(host='10.7.0.115',database=r'C:\ProgramData\Entensys\UserGate6\USERGATE.FDB', user='SYSDBA', password='masterkey',charset='UTF8' )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 653, in connect
    load_api()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 183, in load_api
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__],'api',fbclient_API(fb_library_name))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\fdb\ibase.py", line 1173, in __init__
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, baseKey)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Can not find the specified file
```

This file exist.I know.

Comment: Sorry, I fortgot to translate. There is "Can not find the specified file "

Comment: Just verify: Using Double blackslashes \\

Comment: I tried this. The same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install fbclient.dll on the system , no need for full server (you can uncheck at install time )

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the client .DLL and the necessary registry settings are not installed by default.

After installing the Windows 'Superserver' you need to navigate to the install folder and run two little programs as administrator.  Why this is not done for you during install is beyond me.

Start -> Run -> 'cmd'  -Right click and "Run as Administrator"

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin
instclient i f
instreg i
```

Running the above 'instXXX' programs without parameters returns help.